How to Get Rid of Unnecessary JavaScript in the Coverage Tab After Building and Running Your Gridsome App
Summary:
I'm utilizing Gridsome alongside Bootstrap to craft a fully personalized and content-rich website. Here's an outline:

I retrieve content from Strapi and generate HTML files during the Gridsome build process.
To ensure readiness for production, I split chunks into smaller sizes.
I integrate seven external libraries (e.g., Poptin, GTags, Zoho Analytics, Hotjar) into my project. Previously, they were loaded in the main thread but have now been shifted to Partytown for optimization.
I utilize PurgeCSS to eliminate unused CSS, aiming to enhance website performance.

Despite successfully implementing these steps and achieving satisfactory performance in local builds, I encounter significant performance issues when generating reports on the production server. How can I address this discrepancy, and what could potentially be causing it?
Note: Server space has been verified and is not considered a contributing factor.
On local server build

On production server build

Thanks in advance
